# How do I understand a function that returns a function?

Tags: javascript, return-value, return-type, currying, program-flow

Here's the example code I'm struggling with:

```
function greaterThan(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return y > x;
  };
}

var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10);
show(greaterThanTen(9));
```

Is there a way to put it in math terms or follow the flow or something?  *I don't know why 10 is x and 9 is y.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: no, this is **not** _how do closures work_, this is about lambda calculus and currying.

Comment: Japanese curry or Indian curry?

Comment: Actually named after Haskell Curry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10);
```

You are assinging the variable x to the value 10 and then you store the function in the greaterThanTen Variable to be called later.  this means that:

```
greaterThanTen = function(y) {
    return y > 10;
};
```

So when you do:

```
greaterThanTen(9);  #y = 9
```

You are calling:

```
return 9 > 10;
```

Comment: Are you sure it means `greaterThanTen = function(y)...` and not `greaterThanTen(10) = function(y)...`?

Comment: Ahah.  Apparently you don't.  Cool.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 yes, he does.  `var greaterThanTen` is assigned the (function) result of calling `greaterThan(10)`.

Answer (score 3):

This function doesn't *call* a function, it *returns* a function.

This code is creating a new *unary* function where the original *binary* (greater than) operator's right-hand operand is *prebound* to a specific value.

In [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) this binding is known as [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

In Javascript the binding happens because the supplied value of the parameter `x` in `greaterThan` is permanently retained in the scope of the inner function (or "closure") that is returned.

So, when you call:

```
var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10);
```

what you now have is a *new* function (named `greaterThanTen`) which *always* compares its single parameter to the bound value of 10.

Hence:

```
greaterThanTen(9);
```

will return `false`.

Comment: That's cool.  I have to read about currying to see how it works before I can talk with you about it, though.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what `→` means in `(X →Y) →Z`?

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the edit.  Nice resources.  I don't see how 10 is being held, but it's interesting to know that it is....  Is it held just because of the environment?

Comment: +1, but maybe you should explain how js functions creates scope to help the OP understand why it works the way it does. a good link for reference is here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Comment: @MartinJespersen I added some more text about scope

Answer (score 1):

- Create `greaterThan(10)`
- Create function:
  `function(y){return y > x}`
- return function.

So, when you call `greaterThan(10)`, the function returns a function whose local variable `x` is set to 10.

`var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10)` equals:
`var greaterThanTen = function(y){return y > 10};`

To finish, `greaterThanTen(9)` is called, which equals `9 > 10`, which is false.

Comment: Thanks. The comparisons are OK, I accidentally swapped X and Y.

Comment: yes, the wrong way around.  And 9 is _not_ greater than 10 ;-)

Comment: and the answer should be false 8-)

Comment: I like this explanation because it's easy to follow.  I wonder if I'm missing something.  Is it supposed to be so cut-and-dry?

Comment: There's no more magic behind it. All remarkable parts have already been captured in -hopefully- obvious phrases.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that **greaterThan** does is to set a value for **x** in

> function(y) {return (y>x);}

and store the resulting function in a variable name, in this case **greaterThanTen**, now with the contents

> function(y) {return (y>10);}

Calling **greaterThanTen(9)** is the same as looking at

> function(y = 9) {return (y>10);}

which is the same as

> function(y = 9) {return (9>10);}

which is false. Hence **false** is returned.

***Edit:***

Example of function that returns a function here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iKQA.jpg (x and y is switched around in y>x)

Namaste

Comment: What confuses me, though, is that 9 is held when 10 seems to be passed as a new value.

Comment: It's easier with pictures: If you are used to picturing functions as small flow-machines like me, just picture a small flow-machine returning another small flow-machine: http://i.imgur.com/aiHSH.jpg

I switched around x and y in y>x but you get the idea hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

The `greaterThanTen` variable represents a function taking one argument and returning a boolean value whether this argument is greater then 10.